# Bitcoin wallets

Tags: bitcoin-core

0
down vote

Hello I hope someone can help me please, basically I have made an offline paper wallet. Let's bare in mind I have no printer or camera phone. Anyway I made the paper wallet offline.I deleted a few digits offline and wrote them down safely Came back online..cleared my browser and cache etc. I made a note of the public key..and sent funds from Paxful.com to my public key in my paper wallet. I even checked the transaction on block chain explorer it had been sent. Now I have my private key...I've just read it should always start with a number 5..well my private key does not start with a number 5. Secondly it seems longer than my public key. What I want to know is can I withdraw or spend or send out again or have I lost them because I never scanned them?

Comment: i know why my private key starts with a 6 because its a  password paraphase i used in bitaddress.org to create the paper offline wallet.

Comment: Please edit your post to use a more descriptive title.

Comment: and delete "0 down vote"

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Wallet Details' in bitaddress.org to regenerate your address from your private key or WIF (the password protected key that starts with 6)

If the address that you sent too (or have the funds) matches the one regenerated from your private key, then your safe and your funds are redeemable